# Zookeeper java.net.NoRouteToHostException when connecting

Tags: java, linux, apache, apache-zookeeper

Apologies in advance for the data dump here.  I have two servers with Zookeeper installed.  I want to run them as an ensemble.  Here is what's in my zoo.cfg for both.

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/data
server.1=solr1:2888:3888
server.2=solr2:2888:3888
clientPort=2181
```

Both servers have a myid file. Their names are in the /etc/hosts files, so they can definitely see each other.  When I start either of them by using zkServer.sh, it says zookeeper is started.  However, when I run "zkServer.sh status", I see this message:

```
Using config: /opt/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

But the zookeeper java process seems to be running and using netstat shows tcp ports 3888 and 2181 as listening.  When I try to connect to the server using "sh zkCli.sh -server localhost:2181", I see a bunch of environment info and then a whole bunch of these log entries:

```
2014-02-03 15:39:00,623 [myid:] - INFO [main-SendThread(localhost.localdomain:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@966] - Opening socket connection to server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2014-02-03 15:39:00,646 [myid:] - INFO [main-SendThread(localhost.localdomain:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@849] - Socket            connection established to localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
JLine support is enable
2014-02-03 15:39:00,662 [myid:] - INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost.localdomain:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1085] - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

If I try to connect to the other server (sh zkCli.sh -server solr1:2181), I see a bunch of these:

```
2014-02-03 15:40:42,390 [myid:] - WARN  [main-SendThread(solr1:2181):ClientCnxn$SendThread@1089] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

Zookeeper seems to be running, despite zkServer.sh status saying otherwise.  But does anyone have any insight into my connection issues?  OS is RHEL 6.4, 64 bit.

Comment: Have you opened up the appropriate ports in iptables?

Comment: That was indeed the problem.  I disabled iptables (this is only a dev environment) and that fixed it.  I'm using AWS and was using the security groups feature to control open ports.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

aha, I just resolve the same problem now , and the OS is Centos7. I check all the configure files but can't help. finally, I modified the iptable to add such port: 2181,2888,3888 ,then restart the zookeeper server, it works . one of the cmd is like:
  firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2181/udp --add-port=2181/tcp --permanent
then reloat : 
  firewall-cmd --reload
of course,you can shutdown the iptables and disable the iptables to load at start the OS to achieve this.
  other more ,you should check whether there is a "myid" file in your data path:dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/data and its owner  should be "username:groupUsername";
  May it will help you too.

Answer (score 1):

I may not be an expert on zookeeper, but I have installed zookeeper in ensemble mode on 4 machine cluster on RedHat. I was having the same issue i tired everything available on stackoverflow, after trying everything what i did was
* turned off iptables and firewall on all machines but still there was error, after a few thoughts i tired
* enabling password Less ssh for all machines and this solved my problem now my zookeper's are up and running on all 4 machines

Answer (score -4):

The problem is solved after disable iptables